# Why skype doesn't launch in Ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: 16.04, skype

I had installed Skype in my Ubuntu 16.4 and it doesn't launch I installed it using commands below:

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

any help ?

Comment: What happens when you try to launch it? Is there any error message?

Comment: No it appeared small refresh icon trying to open it and nothing happened and closed

Comment: Skype for Linux got completely new client a while ago. When was the last time you have used Skype?

Comment: I was using it today, but I wanted to update my version by removing and then reinstall it. This is my fault , I really need it :(

Comment: Have you tried running from terminal? Do you get some error messages when you run `skypeforlinux` in terminal?

Comment: @kulfy yes ,but I didn't get any messages

Comment: What is the output of `which skypeforlinux` and `/usr/bin/skypeforlinux`?

Comment: Thanks @kulfy I have restored it :)

Comment: @NaseemMahasneh Glad to see you solved it. You might like to post what you did as answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I run the following commands : 

1- ````sudo wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb````
2- ````sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb````
3- ````sudo apt-get install -f ````
4- ````skypeforlinux````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands :

1- `sudo wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb`

2- `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`

3-`sudo apt-get install -f 4- skypeforlinux –`